# How to make a calculated column but based on each group of rows?

Tags: python, pandas

Considering the inputs below :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['ID1', 'ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4', 'ID4'],
                   'CONTAINER': ['CAT1', 'CAT2', 'CAT3', 'CAT2', 'CAT1', 'CAT2'],
                   'FREE_POSITIONS': [1, 5, 32, 0, 5, 10]})

needed_positions = {"ID1": 3, "ID2": 5, "ID3": 2, "ID4": 2}

    ID CONTAINER  FREE_POSITIONS
0  ID1      CAT1               1
1  ID1      CAT2               5
2  ID2      CAT3              32
3  ID3      CAT2               0
4  ID4      CAT1               5
5  ID4      CAT2              10
```

I need to create a new column: `POSITIONS_TO_ALLOCATE` (as below):

```
    ID CONTAINER  FREE_POSITIONS  POSITIONS_TO_ALLOCATE
0  ID1      CAT1               1                      1
1  ID1      CAT2               5                      2
2  ID2      CAT3              32                      5
3  ID3      CAT2               0                      0
4  ID4      CAT1               5                      2
5  ID4      CAT2              10                      0
```

To explain the logic behind this new column, for example in the group `"ID1"`, this one needs 3 positions to allocate but in `"CAT1"` we have only 1 free position, so we will allocate 1 position for `"ID1"` in this category. We will do the same thing for the other category (which is `"CAT2"`), since we need 2 (three minus one) more positions for "ID1" and `"CAT2"` has 32 free positions, then we'll allocate 2 positions for `"ID1"` in `"CAT2"`. And so on ..

I started making a code and not only it looks awful/long, it also does not work !

```
L = []
for name, g in df.groupby("ID"):
    for _, row in g.iterrows():
        print(row["FREE_POSITIONS"] >= needed_positions.get(row["ID"]))
        if row["FREE_POSITIONS"] >= needed_positions.get(row["ID"]):
            row["NEW"] = needed_positions.get(row["ID"])
        else:
            #wondering what to put here
        L.append(g)
    
out = pd.concat(L)
```

Is there any chance we can achieve my expected result ?

Comment: What happens if `ID1;CAT1 ` has 5 open positions? Do you fill al the need positions in `CAT1`? What happens to `CAT2` in that situation, nothing?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for pointing this out. If `ID1;CAT1` has 5 free positions, then `ID1;CAT1` will have 3 POSITIONS_TO_ALLOCATE and `ID1;CAT2` will have 0 POSITIONS_TO_ALLOCATE. I updated my question to reflect this scenario (see `ID4`).

Comment: Your starting data has only 5 positions on CAT2, that could be a typo.

Comment: @thevoiddancer, my bad, you're right. It is a typo because I wrote my expected output manually. I fixed it, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
def alloc(x):
    """Compute diff(T - max(T - cumsum(x), 0))"""
    T = needed_positions[x.name]
    v = x.cumsum().rsub(T).clip(0).rsub(T).diff()
    return v.fillna(min(T, x.iloc[0])).astype(int)

df['POSITIONS_TO_ALLOCATE'] = df.groupby('ID')['FREE_POSITIONS'].transform(alloc)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    ID CONTAINER  FREE_POSITIONS  POSITIONS_TO_ALLOCATE
0  ID1      CAT1               1                      1
1  ID1      CAT2               5                      2
2  ID2      CAT3              32                      5
3  ID3      CAT2               0                      0
4  ID4      CAT1               5                      2
5  ID4      CAT2              10                      0
```

**Update**: a step by step demonstration

Suppose you want to allocate 27 positions and you have 4 containers with the following free capacity: 1, 5, 32 and 8. So first container can take 1 position, second container 5 positions, third container take the rest so 21 positions and nothing for the last container. The algorithm is greedy: we completely fill the first container then the second and so on.

```
A = pd.Series([1, 5, 32, 8])
T = 27
S = min(T, A.iloc[0])

s1 = A.cumsum()  # compute cumulative sum
s2 = s1.rsub(T)  # T - s1, greedy allocation
s3 = s2.clip(0)  # max(s2, 0), remove negative allocation
s4 = s3.rsub(T)  # T - s3, real cumulative allocation
s5 = s4.diff().fillna(S).astype(int)  # compute real allocation

out = pd.concat([A, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5], axis=1,
                keys=['A', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5'])
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    A  s1  s2  s3  s4  s5
0   1   1  26  26   1   1
1   5   6  21  21   6   5
2  32  38 -11   0  27  21
3   8  46 -19   0  27   0
```

The key in this problem is to clip negative allocations. It doesn't mean nothing to take -11 or -19 positions! The cumulative sum is used here to allow vectorized operations. At the end, we use a "cumulative sub" (diff) to return individual positions.

Comment: I'm very impressed. I'll need some days before understanding your alloc function. I don't know how to thank you Corralien, you made/saved my week, have a nice day.

Comment: I agree, this looks VERY impressive. Here, an upvote!

Comment: Although, I compared the execution time, and my approach is not significantly slower, which I would expect. @Corralien, could you detect what is the longest step in your code? Is it the transform() method?

Comment: @thevoiddancer have you compared the two approaches on a large dataset? Vectorization often reveals its power on large enough data ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try if this works:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['ID1', 'ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4', 'ID4'],
                   'CONTAINER': ['CAT1', 'CAT2', 'CAT3', 'CAT2', 'CAT1', 'CAT2'],
                   'FREE_POSITIONS': [1, 5, 32, 0, 5, 10]})

needed_positions = {"ID1": 3, "ID2": 5, "ID3": 2, "ID4": 2}


def assign_pos(row):
    global need
    row['allocated_positions'] = min(need, row['FREE_POSITIONS'])
    need -= row['allocated_positions']
    return row

for pos, need in needed_positions.items():
    df.loc[df['ID'] == pos, 'allocated_positions'] = df.loc[df['ID'] == pos, :].apply(assign_pos, axis='columns')['allocated_positions']

print(df)
```

Personally, I dislike the apply version, but it's the first one I thought of.

Anyways, the idea is that we're using assign_pos to create a new column and reduce the number that needs to be allocated. This will work good enough for smaller frames, but if you're talking about thousands of rows or more, then this might need a significant rework.

Comment: Thinking about this, I'm not sure we can avoid apply.

Apply iterates over rows, it behaves something like `for row in df`, which makes it slower than vectorised approach (which is similar to multithreading). However, we have to update the number after each assignment, which I'm not sure can be done with vectorized approach.

Maybe using groupby and then making a partial sum over a group?

Comment: Thank you so much my friend for you help, I really appreciate it. Your code worked for me (my dataset isn't huge). Btw, @Corralien gave a vectorized approach.